# Is there any cost (in terms of dollars) associated with using Azure SAS?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I couldn't figure out if there is any cost, in terms of dollars, associated with using Shared Access Signatures (SAS) tokens of Azure?
It will be great if anyone can point me in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Microsoft Azure support. This site is for programming questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sas tokens do not cost anything extra. you only pay for the usage

Comment: What is the cost of usage? Is based on transactions? I can't find the rate for that.

Comment: yeah, traffic, io, storage  
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/

Comment: That cost is there even without SAS. so there is 'No' extra cost of using SAS?

Comment: Yes I did...your link confused me..maybe you gave to help out on second look makes sense..thanks